# Why isnt the image scrolling?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h0 style= "text-align:left; float:left; font-size:40px">Birds of the World</h0>

<nav>
<table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:80">
<tr>
<th><button><a href="species.html">Species</a></button>
<button><a href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a></button>
<button><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></button>
<button><a href="competitions.html">Competitions</a></button>
<button><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></button>
</nav>

<h2 style="position:relative; left:-747px; top:45px; background-color:white; float:left; font-size:30px">What to expect</h2>
<h3 style="position:relative; left: -1050px; top:70px; background-color:white; float:centre; font-size:20px">Photography</h3>
<center>
<marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="left"> 
<img style="float; position:absolute; left: 10px; top:160px;" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/3972/production/_117860741_0cce322a-ecd2-4c8e-9661-0356978237a3.jpg" alt="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/3972/production/_117860741_0cce322a-ecd2-4c8e-9661-0356978237a3.com" width="300" height="150"</img>
</marquee>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

So I have recently gotten in to HTML and have started messing around with 'Marquee' recently and just wanted to ask why this image isn't scrolling (it should be the bottom few lines). I included the rest of the code just in case its a problem with the rest of the code. I have tries removing the 'position' part of the image, and that does make the image scroll, but only in a small box on the right. Is there some problem with how I have formatted my code? I am extremely new to HTML so it may just be something extremely simple that is flying over my head.

Comment: There is no such thing as the `<h0>` tag, and the `<center>` and `<marquee>` tags are obsolete, outdated, and/or deprecated

Comment: Thanks. Are there any tags that I could use to replace <marquee> and <center>?

Comment: Not only that your tags are not well-formed (missing closing tags on table-row and table, invalid img closing tag)

Comment: I (think) I fixed that now, but it still hasn't changed anything about the image not scrolling or just scrolling in a small box. Is there anything else I am missing that might be preventing it from scrolling.